# How can I stop a CSS3 animation from jumping back to the beginning when finished

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS3 animation, that simply moves a `<div>` down (via `top: 0px;` to `top: 300px;`). But my problem is, I don't know how to prevent the `<div>` from returning to the top when the animation is finished. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Here's a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8tJ7/

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to invert the animation like so.

```
@keyframes move {
  from{
    top: 20px;
  }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/y8tJ7/1/

This way its finishing position is specified in the div styling and you only specify the beginning state in the keyframe.

**EDIT**: Another way of achieving it could be to simply add:

`animation-fill-mode: forwards`.

See this other [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/y8tJ7/2/).

Some more info about it on [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Comment: Yes!! `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. Perfect! Exactly what I need!

Comment: This just saved my life. Perfect solution.

Comment: Yep, perfect solution (the edit).